# 3-dB frequency of cascaded opamps

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, frequency, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

We have two identical opamps with a first order low-pass response. They both have the same 3-dB frequency \$f_1\$.

I need to show that their combined 3-dB frequency (when they are put in cascade) is:

\$f_{3dB} = \sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}f_1\$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Hello, João, welcome to EE Stack Exchange! This appears to be a homework problem. The general rule here with homework problems is that you need to show all the work you've done thus far, and explain where you're getting stuck. This helps us help you develop your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st order LPF response is 1/(1+jf/f1). When f = f1, it becomes 1/(1+j) with magnitude of 1/sqrt(2), corresponding to -3dB.
When two of these are cascaded, the freq. response becomes, [1/(1+jf/f1)]^2 with magnitude of 1/[1+(f/f1)^2]. Set it to 1/sqrt(2), then 1/[1+(f/f1)^2] = 1/sqrt(2), then solving f gives f3dB = sqrt[sqrt(2)-1]*f1.